# Can I create a 301 redirect from www.xcompany.com to shop.xcompany.com?

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo, redirect, http-status-code-301

I work for xcompany.  I am wondering if it is possible to set up a 301 redirect from our site http://shop.xcompany.com/ to our site http://www.xcompany.com/ and if possible, what would the rewrite rules be?

The old page that existed on the former URL has been removed from the site and a similar page has been created on the latter URL and we need to make sure any traffic is directed to the new page.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^old/URL/path$ http://example.com/new/path [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from **oldsite.com** to **newsite.com** you can use the following redirect in **/oldsite/.htaccess**

```
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting one domain to another domain is very much easier than before only if you are well familiar with CMSs like WordPress. There are plenty of redirect plug-ins available in WordPress that make our efforts easier and quicker.

301 redirection must be done if you have made any changes to the older URL and it will give link juices without losing its ranking, backlinks, and all others.

You need not worry about anything. Redirect your older one to new one. Then Google webmaster tool will give a report if your new site causes crawling errors. Hope it'd be helpful.